# How to programmatically assign roles and permissions to services and/or RequestDTOs

Tags: servicestack

Statically I set access to my services like so:

```
[Authenticate]
public class AppUserService : Service
{
    [RequiredRole("Administrator")]
    public object Post(CreateAppUser request)
    {
         //.....
    }
}
```

How can I do this programmatically?

I will let the user create roles using a GUI. Then I will present a list of available methods, e.g. by providing the methods using improved code like:

```
        var appHost = HostContext.AppHost;
        var restPaths = appHost.RestPaths;
        foreach (var restPath in restPaths)
        {
            var reqType = restPath.RequestType;
            string verbs = string.Empty;
            if (restPath.Verbs != null)
            {
                var counter = 0;
                foreach (var verb in restPath.Verbs)
                {
                    if (counter > 0) verbs += ", ";
                    verbs += verb;
                    counter++;
                }  
            }
            Debug.WriteLine($"Path: {restPath.Path} | Verbs: {verbs} | Name: {reqType.Name} FullName: {reqType.FullName}");
        }
```

The code above outputs something like

```
Path: /appusers | Verbs: POST | Name: CreateAppUser FullName: MyServer.ServiceModel.DTOs.Request.CreateAppUser
```

So I could show in my UI the `Name` property of the `RequestType` and let him define, what roles are allowed to call this method. So the user may create a role called 'User Management' and allow members of this role to execute `CreateAppUser`.

Using annotations I would write

```
[RequiredRole("Administrator", "User Management")]
public object Post(CreateAppUser request)
{ .... }
```

Is this anyhow possible in C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack does have a way to dynamically Add Attributes at runtime, e.g:

```
typeof(CreateAppUser)
  .AddAttributes(new RequiredRoleAttribute("Administrator", "User Management"));
```

Which is an alternative to declaring attributes statically, but it's still not a solution for a data-driven authorization system.

But you could add your own custom Authorization logic in addition to ServiceStack's built-in attributes by validating it in your Service:

```
public ICustomAuth CustomAuth { get; set; }

public object Post(CreateAppUser request)
{
    var session = base.GetSession();
    var requiresRoles = CustomAuth.GetRequiredRoles(request.GetType());
    var hasAllRoles = requiresRoles.All(r => 
        session.HasRole(r, base.AuthRepository))
    if (!hasAllRoles)
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Requires all roles");
}
```

If you do this a lot you will want to refactor the custom validation logic into a single reusable method, or if you prefer into a custom RequestFilter attribute.

Comment: Thanks Demis, I think a custom RequestFilter is the preferable way to do it. I'll try later.